# How do i request the newly created model with mongoose and Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I´m creating a sport site where Users can create Teams. I want the new Team created to be automatically pushed into the Users membership and leadership arrays. But I can't figure out how to request the newly created Team as shown in the code below:

```
const Team = require('../models/Team.js')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = async (req,res)=>{
   await Team.create({
        ... req.body,
        teamName: req.body.teamname ,
        sportType: req.body.sporttype,
        description: req.body.description,
        location: req.body.location,
        members: [req.session.userId],
        leaders: [req.session.userId]
    });


        const user = await req.session.userId;
        const teams = //Request newly created Team
        await user.leadership.push(teams)
        await user.membership.push(teams)
        await user.save()
    res.redirect('/')

}
```

Here is the Schema for User:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true 
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    membership: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Team' }],
    leadership: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Team'}]
});
```

Here is the Schema for Team:

```
const TeamSchema = new Schema({
    teamName: String,
    sportType: String,
    description: String,
    location: String,
    members: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    leaders: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
})
```

Comment: did you miss to export the model like :
module.exports = mongoose.model('collection_name', TeamSchema )

Comment: If you mean in the User and Team Schema, then no, I left those parts out in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
module.exports = async (req,res)=>{
    const user = User.findById(req.session.userId)
    const teams = await Team.create({
        ... req.body,
        teamName: req.body.teamname ,
        sportType: req.body.sporttype,
        description: req.body.description,
        location: req.body.location,
        members: [req.session.userId],
        leaders: [req.session.userId]
    });
    await user.leadership.push(teams)
    await user.membership.push(teams)
    await user.save()
    res.redirect('/')
}
```

Try this. Also, the better approach will be to create different functions for creating the object and then calling it here.

Comment: Thank you! It worked, just had to change to  "const user = User.findById(req.session.userId)"

Comment: Could you describe in more how I would do that? I'm new to this, thanks

Comment: @Rohlig Happy to help. I edited the answer as you said. Explanation: await Team.create will give an object of the team schema in response and that object is used to add in the user object. If this works as an answer for you. Please mark it as an accepted answer.

Comment: @Nyan Lathiya, I meant how might I go about creating different functions for creating the object and then calling it here.

Comment: [Reference Link](https://dev.to/ama/mongoose-calls-examples-with-async-await-in-an-expressjs-api-4ffh) please let me know if you still have some doubts.